# Passing Dictionary scripting object as parameter

Tags: object, dictionary, vbscript, scripting, asp-classic

I have declared an object like this:

```
dim oTest
oTest = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
oTest.Add ("a", "Red")
oTest.Add ("b", "Blue")
```

and I want to pass this information to another page like this:

```
response.redirect ("nextpage.aspx?username=fred&paramstring=" & oTest)
```

but I'm getting this error:

> Operator '&' is not defined for string "nextpage.aspx?username=fred" and type 'Dictionary'.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The reason for the error is objects `oTest` cannot be pass directly to `String` variables, VBScript / Classic ASP doesn't support serialising objects you have to do that yourself using the various functions / methods available to you in VBScript.

Comment: the error you have is strange for VBScript, and calling methods with paranthesis also. are you sure that this is an ASP / VBScript question? it seems to me a Visual Basic .NET (ASP.Net) question.

Comment: No, I'm using Classic ASP. We have .NET libraries installed but I don't know if the code makes use of them. It seems I can't use the Dictionary object for passing parameters between pages: looks like I'm stuck with concatenated strings. I was hoping to use something more sophisticated. But I appreciate your help and your feedback!

Comment: OK, here's what I can do. On the original page I assign the object to a session variable: 

session("testobject") = oTest 

and then after I get to the next page, I do this: 

dim oTest
oTest = session("testobject")

and then I can use the values like this: 

oTest.Item("a") 

This does just about everything I originally needed! Thank you all

Comment: Now I'm pretty sure that you're on VB.Net. 1- you're redirecting to a page called `nextpage.aspx` and `aspx` is an asp.net extension. 2- in VBScript your code cannot not compile due to error `Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub` by addressing `oTest.Add (` lines. 3- `oTest = CreateObject("..` is not a valid object assignment in `VBScript`, it should be `Set oTest = CreateObject("..`. More evidence? And yes, you can store the object in Session, it works for both ASP Classic and ASP.Net.

Answer (score 1):

Functions to (de)serialize a Dictionary:

```
Option Explicit

Const csSD1 = "&"
Const csSD2 = "="

' make dictionary from string containing serialized dictionary (key-csSD2-value-csSD1-...)
Function s2d(s)
  Dim d : Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim e, p
  For Each e In Split(s, csSD1)
      p = Split(e, csSD2)
      d(p(0)) = p(1)
  Next
  Set s2d = d
End Function

' serialize dictionary to string (key-csSD2-value-csSD1-...)
Function d2s(d)
  Dim a : a = d.Keys
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(a)
       a(i) = Join(Array(a(i), d(a(i))), csSD2)
  Next
  d2s = Join(a, csSD1)
End Function

Dim s : s = "a=red&b=blue"
Dim d : Set d = s2d(s)
If s = d2s(d) Then WScript.Echo "ok"
```

Comment: special characters must be escaped, otherwise `s2d` may return incorrect key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

The `Scripting.Dictionary` has two methods that might be helpful.

- `.Keys()` - Returns an `Array` of the keys
- `.Items() - Returns an`Array` of the items

Using the two Arrays you could iterate through them and build up a String. Something like this should work.

```vb
<%
Dim DirTest
Dim DirKeys, DirItems
Dim Index, NumOfKeys, Params

Set DirTest = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With DirTest
  Call .Add("a", "Red")
  Call .Add("b", "Blue")
  DirKeys = .Keys()
  DirItems = .Items()
End With
If IsArray(DirKeys) Then
  Params = ""
  NumOfKeys = UBound(DirKeys)
  For Index = 0 To NumOfKeys
    Params = Params & DirKeys(Index) & "=" & DirItems(Index) & "&"
  Next
  'Trim the last Ampersand
  Params = Left(Params, Len(Params) - 1)
  Response.Write Params
End If
%>
```

Output:

```
a=Red&b=Blue
```

Comment: Thank you both for this. It looks like the Dictionary object won't help at all, since I will have to dismantle it before moving to another page. I will have to think again! I appreciate all you help!